# Selenium not randomly clicking (No Error Code)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Process finished with exit code 0.  Selenium is not randomly clicking…
It navigates up to this part of the job below (I assume and finishes successfully) however nothing is clicked or scraped.

```
indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
shuffle(indexes)
for index in indexes:
    wait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
```

And then the jobs stops.  There is no error message unfortunately.  It does not seem to scrape the pages either or even click the tabs.

Any ideas on what is causing this issue. I have tried different Xpaths but there seems to be no errors.

Here is my full [code](https://pastebin.com/bJ1J5zxF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code waits for the elements to be clickable, but never actually clicks on the elements.

One possible solution:

```
clickMe= wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'(//div[div/div/text()="Main Lists"]//div[starts-with(@class, "sm-CouponLink_Label") and normalize-space()])[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
clickMe.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the cause of the problem, but I encountered it in one of ours applications that use [SmartGWT framework](https://www.smartclient.com/product/smartgwt.jsp). Nothing worked, the button seemed always to be visible and clickable for WebDriver, and sometimes responded to the click, but most often did not.

We solved that in such a way, that after clicking the button we wait a few seconds for the effect of clicking this button (some text should apper on the screen, a window should dissapear etc.), and if the effect does not appear - the button is clicked again and again in a loop.
One of the buttons got a record (we record retries in the log) -
 had to be clicked 13 times before it responded.

---

Another method which sometimes works in this case is to sending ENTER key to the button rather than click on it, that is:

```
findElement( button ).sendKeys( Keys.ENTER );
```